having probelms with PyQt5 and ubuntu 24.04
I'm struggling to get PyQt5 working on my ubuntu 24.04 installation. when I run my python application here's what I get.
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), linuxfb (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), minimal (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), minimalegl (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), offscreen (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), vnc (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), wayland-egl (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), wayland (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), wayland-xcomposite-egl (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), wayland-xcomposite-glx (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), xcb (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms), eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb, webgl.

Aborted (core dumped)

I have installed and reinstalled Qt5 and PyQt5 and tried various things with reloading various libraries but I cannot seem to get past this core dump problem. Running on a Geekom IT12 if that is relevant. Anyone else seeing similar problems out there?

thanks for that answer, I could not find a snap package for qt5-core24 (so I installed qt5-core22) but will that work with ubuntu 24.04? I'm still getting the same error at runtime.

Remove qt with --purge.
Install again.
I think you need that core 24 and 22 or 18.
You can find there:
https://snapcraft.io/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
